# Структура меша для рендеринга

Tags: c, разработка-игр, render, vulkan

Хочу сделать простой рендерер obj файлов, я написал такой код для загрузки obj файла:

```
typedef struct {
    // Тут должен храниться obj файл в оптимальном для загрузки на GPU и рендеринга виде
} mesh_t;

void mesh_load(const char *path, mesh_t *mesh) {
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    assert(file);

    int result = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    assert(!result);

    long length = ftell(file);
    assert(length > 0);

    void *data = malloc(length);
    assert(data);

    result = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    assert(!result);

    size_t bytes = fread(data, 1, length, file);
    assert(bytes == (unsigned)length);

    tinyobj_attrib_t attrib;
    tinyobj_shape_t *shapes;
    size_t num_shapes;
    tinyobj_material_t *materials;
    size_t num_materials;

    result = tinyobj_parse_obj(
        &attrib,
        &shapes,
        &num_shapes,
        &materials,
        &num_materials,
        data,
        length,
        TINYOBJ_FLAG_TRIANGULATE
    );
    assert(result == TINYOBJ_SUCCESS);

    // Тут необходимо как-то заполнить память, на которую указывает указатель mesh
}
```

Содержимое функции `tinyobj_parse_obj` располагается тут https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader-c/blob/master/tinyobj_loader_c.h
Но вот дальше застопорился, я не могу понять как хранить данные полученные посредством функции `tinyobj_parse_obj`, я пока на начальном этапе изучения Vulkan API и знаю только что нужно хранить как минимум вершины, индексы и текстурные координаты, но вот везде описывается немного по разному как это необходимо делать и я не могу понять на какой пример ориентироваться, поэтому хотелось бы узнать как все же правильно хранить obj файл в оптимальном для рендеринга виде?(желательно с примером преобразования данных от `tinyobj_parse_obj` в эту структуру)